# only reading till 1st decimal digit

Tags: android

In my android app, I have an EditText in which the user enters a decimal which can be as long as the user wants. It can be a number like 25, 54.77, 23.7, 7.88, etc. In the same activity, I have a textView which reads the input into the EditText and displays the decimal but only till the first decimal digit. For e.g. if the user enters: 25 should be displayed as 25, 54.77 as 54.7, 23.7 as 23.7, 7.88 as 7.8. How can I achieve this? I tried using the following code but it didn't work:

```
        NumberFormat df = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
        df.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
        df.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);

        df.format(EditTextNumber);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.format`:

```
String result = String.format("%.1f", yourdecimalvalue);
```

you can use `DecimalFormat` too:

```
 NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.0");
 String result = formatter.format(yourdeciamlvalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try NumberFormat instead of DecimalFormat:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);
TextView.setText(nf.format(editText.getText()));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are grbbing the input via an edittext then u can use this code

```
String number=input.getText().toString(); //input is ur input edittext
String output=number;
int indexOfDecimal=number.lastIndexOf('.');
if(indexOfDecimal!=-1&&indexOfDecimal<output.length()-1)
    number=output.substring(0, indexOfDecimal+2);  // use number as the output
```